# magento catalog search not working

Tags: magento

I have to make **custom catalog search**. For this I have made a file in **/var/www/magento/customsearch.php** and put following code:

```
$searchText = 'test';

$query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($searchText)->prepare();

$fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
        Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'), 
        $searchText, 
        $query
        );

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
            array('search_result' => $collection->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
            $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
                $query->getId()
            )
        );

print_r($collection->getData());
```

But the collection returns blank array.It update catalogsearch query table each time but not update catalogsearch result table. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I put your same code on my Magento website:

```
<?php

include "app/Mage.php";

Mage::app();

$searchText = 'test';

$query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($searchText)->prepare();

$fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
        Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'), 
        $searchText, 
        $query
        );

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
            array('search_result' => $collection->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
            $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
                $query->getId()
            )
        );

print_r($collection->getData());
```

And got an array with three of my products. So I guess, check your setup? You have products right? With the keyword 'test' some where in the attribute values?

Comment: put this code on root directory file as i mension then it will not work.